# Chromecast Custom Receiver Show Different Content by Language

Tags: android, chromecast, custom-receiver

I wrote a sender in android and wrote a custom receiver, I have a problem that how can I know to show different language content from receiver when sender connected

Answer (score 0):

On the sender side, when you want to launch your application on a cast device, you can provide additional data in the api that launches the app by providing a [LaunchOptions](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/LaunchOptions) parameter (see [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/Cast.CastApi.html#launchApplication(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20com.google.android.gms.cast.LaunchOptions)), for example). One of the parameters there is language and once you set that, when the cast device requests your receiver, it includes the appropriate "Accept-Language" header and your server can provide the appropriate page to the cast device.

Comment: Any example of it, I found a lot of web site that no any example fit to me